# Defer the execution of some ~/.bash-files commands, to be non-blocking

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, shell, macos-mojave

I have my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` being loaded at shell start; except for some `export` and `alias`, there's a command that needs a couple of seconds to run:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

And I need to wait this 2 seconds delay all the times I open a new terminal.

Given that I almost never use NVM and that I don't need it to be ready immediately after shell loading,

- how can I **delay the execution** of that command? (e.g. running 10 seconds after the shell is loaded)
- how can I set the execution of such command to be asynchronous so that it **doesn't block** the fast loading and readiness of my shell?

Comment: Answered on [so]. See [bash - executing shell command in background from script - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683910/executing-shell-command-in-background-from-script)

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" &>/dev/null` still blocks the shell and I can't use it until it finished executing that command.

Comment: Try putting parentheses around the command like so `([ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh")`

Comment: Then it creates a new block scope and the run scripts don't do what they should (register/alias *nvm\** commands that need to be available in the shell); because (I suppose) it runs in the sub-shell but nothing is being changed inside the original one.

Comment: {shrug} I'll wait for a bash/macos expert to answer then ...

Comment: Thank you anyway for the effort. ⥊ *Note:* I also tried to add `&disown` and it runs faster... but then there's no *nvm* alias registered in the opened shell. [Probably same issue with scope]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried; but adding the space in between there makes the command ineffective (no error; just, the script won't register the *nvm\** aliases on the shell where it's executed)

Comment: You source a shell script, expecting it to set environment variables. It must be very tricky getting this to work asynchronously ... I would love to learn of a solution. I would expect it's impossible.

Comment: Another solution would be to lazy-load that script, provided that there are only a limited number of commands that could possibly need the environment variables it sets. That is, you replace the real commands with shell aliases that load the script behind the scenes. Am I talking sense?

Comment: Yes, you are. That might be an interesting approach ; I have to check how to implement it. – From what I read around, this issue is mostly related to OSX's inability to load the `.bash_profile` just once, at user login (so I could put the script there). Or, better, is due to the fact that OSX **always** loads a login-shell, hence **always** loading the `.bash_profile` (and re-running each time that slow script).